# Generating a report and then emailing it

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I currently have my form that has a field that, when clicked, executes some VBA code in an Event Procedure that opens a report:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "GirlScoutandTroopMatchNoParams", acViewPreview, , "[TroopLeaders.Troop]=" & Me.Troop, acWindowNormal
```

What I need to do now is automatically generate an email and attach that report to the email.

Is there a way to do this?

Brand new to Access development, so don't assume I know anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will convert the report to PDF and attach it to an new email using your default email client:

```
gTroop = Me.Troop 'global variable to be defined in global module and accessed from the query using a function
DoCmd.OpenReport "GirlScoutandTroopMatchNoParams", acViewPreview, , "TroopLeaders.Troop=" & Me.Troop
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "<NameOfReport>", "PDF", "johnbloggs@gmail.com"
```

You can use some more parameters to include subject and/or body text and/or to denote whether or not the email gets sent without showing in the email client.

The problem is that `SendObject` does not provide an option for specifying criteria!
Therefore you have to write the report's underlying query, in such a way that it can get the criteria from the global variable.

```
Public Function GetTroopValue() as long
   GetTroopValue = gTroop
End Function
```

Then in the underlying query you will use:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Troop = GetTroopValue()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but what if I need to first create the report using a WHERE clause, and then email it.  Again, I might be missing something very simple.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to generate the report

Comment: DoCmd.OpenReport "GirlScoutandTroopMatchNoParams", acViewPreview, , "[TroopLeaders.Troop]=" & Me.Troop, acWindowNormal.       What I want is to combine that with the line of code you provided I believe so that I can pluck the report I created using the field on the form and then email it using the email address that is also on the form

Comment: Thanks!  So to be sure (as I am doing this from memory and at work right now...) in your example gTroop is actually the field on the form.  As in Me.Troop.  Does the report really have addressability to the form's fields?

Comment: No! gTroop is a global variable, nothing to do with the form.

Comment: Darn. So my original question still exists then I think.  I need to pass in the form's field value for 'Troop' to the report and email the report that is based solely on that field's value.  Am I out of luck in your opinion?

Comment: I clearly explained what to do. Learn up how to use global variables in VBA. This is easily done.

Comment: Before you open the report `gTroop = me.Troop`